# Android push token getting reset

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are experiencing an issue in production where the push being sent out has many active devices with invalid tokens 10%.
One diagnosis is the app's push token can be invalidated if the unique id of the app is reset.

What would be the situations when this may occur?

- App reinstalled
- App data/cache cleaned?

How does firebase push token fetching, refresh and storing work internally?

Where is app unique id stored in OS?

Is this a valid scenario?

```
[google reset token in device]->[app not opened and not aware of changed token]->[app backend sends push to old token]
```

What are the ways to ensure token push validity?

Comment: `On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. ` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register AFAIR the token is stored in a preferences file.

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register you can check this for situations.

also you can use something like this

```
_firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
      User _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc("tokens/" + _currentUser.uid)
          .set({"token": newToken});
    });
```

in your homepage. If token changes it will update token in firestore